# APNS library javapns - Will there be ever a new release?

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns

does anyone know when there will be a new release of the Apple push notification java library [javapns](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/)?

I´m asking cause it has a bug that makes trouble for us.

[Issue 187 - Resend feature is incorrect](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?can=2&q=187&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=187)

It causes - in rare cases - to send push notifications twice to the same user, because it assumes an error occured.

The Issue seems to be fixed already:

[Fixed bug in auto-resend feature and added option to disable it if necessary](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/source/detail?r=384)

But that was `Sep 29, 2014`, the last [release](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/downloads/list) however was `Jan 2012`. So anyone knows if they want to release a new version?

Comment: I doubt anyone here knows, unless the person(s) responsible for the decision are here and happen to see your post. Are you still using the old version, or did you build the library from source?

Comment: thanks for your reply. We´re still using the old version from 2012.

Comment: You might want to build your own version then, since there's no guarantee when if ever they'll release a new one.

Comment: we will consider this, thank you. I don´t know how much you´re familiar with the javapns project, but do you know where to contact a person involved in javapns and ask them directly? That would be the last time me bothering you then :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with javapns, but the project has been archived and should be moved off the site soon anyway. Looks like the only active committer is `sypecom`, with a gmail address. It's essentially a one man project.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest library which includes the fix you need (2.3b3) directly from the trunk (in Source, Browse, svn/trunk/JavaPNS_2.3_Beta_3.jar). Although it is labeled as Beta, it seems to be as reliable as the 2.2 release, if not more.

The project is not mine, but I have been the only contributor for the last few years because I needed that functionality for a few past projects. Since I do not need it anymore, I don't think I will have more time to give to that project. Anyone needing that functionality is welcome to help move the project off Google Code and take over development. Thank you! :)